# WSO2 IS Login Form not displaying

Tags: wso2-identity-server

While trying to generate token for one of the service provider. Login form (i.e, Basicauth.jsp) is not being loaded. Upon troubleshooting found that it is due to authenticators query param's value which list of authenticators being seperated by '&' not ';' in login endpoint.

{IS_URL}/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=fLvBMOApx7s_eK4He4Su7g9zqcga&commonAuthCallerPath=/oauth2/authorize&forceAuth=false&nonce=13e2312637dg136e1&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback&response_type=code&scope=openid&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=e8b6ac13-28a6-4c50-a8b0-02875df0b583&relyingParty=fLvBMOApx7s_eK4He4Su7g9zqcga&type=oidc&sp=TEST_SP&isSaaSApp=true&authenticators=GoogleOIDCAuthenticator:Google&LinkedIn:LinkedIN&OpenIDConnectAuthenticator:O365:Skill App:ADP&BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL:LOCAL

IS: v5.10.0

Please suggest what could be the issue. Issue is not occuring in local_is.

[Login Form Not Displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm221.png)

[Outbound authentication configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqR5v.png)

Comment: Are you trying with multi options authentication mechaism? It will be better if you attach the service provider configs including the Local and Outbound configuration?

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah Trying multi options authentication mechanism. Added screenshot for reference.

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah Let me know if you need any further information for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported issue (https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7961) related to your observation in IS-5.10.0.

I suspect you have enabled the following property in your setup.

```
[authentication.authenticator.basic.parameters]
showAuthFailureReason = true
```

Solutions:

1. Patch the changes in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2849/files. (If you have WSO2 subscriptions go for the WUM update.)
2. Remove the basic authenticator's `showAuthFailureReason` property or set it to false.

Comment: Thanks Anuradha. Second solution worked for me.